# Fastest way to update a viewcount from results in SQL query

Tags: sql

I've got a problem and a working solution to update viewvounts on some posts on a website I'm building but I'm looking for the fastest possible way and it feels very long way around

I want to be able to get posts based on lots of different criteria, such as who posted it, last 20 posts, top 20 containing some search text etc but with 2 lots of extra information INNER JOINED which is all easy enough but as I have no interaction other than selecting by some criteria I cant see a way to update the viewcounts for each.

Hopefully if the site goes well this will be heavily used so I am looking to do it as quickly as possible.

The best working solution I have so far is to;

- Open the connection
- Get the posts I want
- Process them onto the web page making a string of all the ID numbers
- run another stored procedure to update the viewcounts of those numbers
- Close the connection

Am I missing something stupidly simple here?

the [Posts] table is simple;

- [PostID] BIGINT
- [PostUserID] INT
- [PostGroupID] INT
- [PostType] INT
- [PostText] NVARCHAR(500)
- [PostLinkText] NVARCHAR(250)
- [Vewcount] INT
- [Likes] INT
- [comments] INT

The code I'm using to update the views is like this:

```
DECLARE @ViewedPosts NVARCHAR(MAX) = '1000|22|13|1000|400101011|22|13|1000|22|13|400101011' 

SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(
[PostID] BIGINT
)
INSERT INTO @Temp
SELECT [Value] AS [PostID] FROM dbo.SPLIT(@ViewedPosts, '|')

DECLARE @PID BIGINT
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Temp)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @PID = [PostID] FROM @Temp
    -- UPDATE [Posts] SET [Viewcount]=[Viewcount]+1 WHERE [PostID]=@PID --
    SELECT [PostID] FROM @Temp WHERE [PostID]=@PID
    DELETE @Temp WHERE [PostID]= @PID
END
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

the dbo.SPLIT just makes a single column table of all the postID's from the viewed posts string.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT 'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'value' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
    FROM Split
)
GO
```

I've done the usual scouring google and stackoverflow but all I am finding is different solutions that work out more or less what I've already got.

UPDATE: Working solution:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE ( [PostIDt] BIGINT )
INSERT INTO @Temp SELECT [PostID] AS [PostIDt] FROM [Posts] WITH(NOLOCK) ORDER BY [POSTID] DESC;
UPDATE [Posts] SET [ViewCount]=[ViewCount]+1 WHERE [PostId] IN (SELECT [PostIDt] AS [PostId] FROM @Temp);
SELECT * FROM @Temp INNER JOIN [Posts] ON [PostIDt] = [Posts].[PostID];
```

Comment: Please tag your database and provide sample data. At a quick glance, while loop is unnecessary and would slow down things. It more looks like a single update command. ie: Update [Posts] set [ViewCount] = [ViewCount] + 1from @temp t wheret.PostId = Posts.PostId. It sounds this SQL server, if so Split function content may be also of value how it is implemented. I would create a CLR function for that, which is exceptionally faster than T-SQL based solution. And also, how do you generate that string of ViewedPosts. That may be written differently.

Comment: I've added a bit more in, the ViewedPosts is literally a string on the webpage back end. So every time a post appears on the page a text string postIDs = postIDs & "|" & reader("PostID") then at the end of getting the posts I'm passing that back to SQL with the above update as another stored procedure. Thats why it feels like I'm missing something, having to run two procedures, one to just get the information and display it then a second to update the viewcounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And now to updating part, the split string contains the same Id multiple times, thus I assume you want to increase by how many times an Id occurs there, not just 1:

```
DECLARE @ViewedPosts NVARCHAR(MAX) =N'1000|22|13|1000|400101011|22|13|1000|22|13|400101011';

SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [Posts]
SET    [ViewCount]=[ViewCount]+tmp.Views
FROM
       (
         SELECT
                  s, COUNT(*) AS Views
         FROM     dbo.ufn_SplitString(@ViewedPosts, '|')
         GROUP BY s
       ) tmp
WHERE  [postId]=tmp.s;
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

EDIT: Getting the posts from SQL server and update all in one call:

```
UPDATE [Posts]
    SET    [ViewCount]=[ViewCount]+1
    WHERE  [postId] in (SELECT TOP(20) PostId 
                        FROM [Posts] 
                        ORDER BY [POSTID] DESC);
```

Comment: I didnt bother with the count as there should never be duplicate posts, the string above was from testing and playing around also if it is twice on a page technically I would want 2 views added, I'm trying to save every fraction of a millisecond and assumed counting would be extra work when it might be only 1 or 2 at the very most and incredibly rare.

Comment: @Modded, it is OK. This way with counting it is safer anyway. It wouldn't have a negative effect, I don't think it would make a millisecond difference. If you are hundred percent sure it wouldn't be duplicated, you may remove counting part and it would then just be from dbo.ufnSplitString(...) x where Posts.PostId = x.s

Comment: @Modded, this last SQL doesn't really seem correct to me increasing the ViewCounts of last 20 PostIds but I think the inner SQL would be edited to give exactly what you want first.

Comment: Thanks that looks more simple and like I'm wanting but the way I will be getting the posts is going to a bit all over the place, for example I will only be getting 1 max entry per [PostGroupID]>1, but as many [PostGroupID]=0 as I have within the TOP 20 so to do this in one hit would it be better to make a temp table of pure [postIDs] from the various methods then update as you suggest and then INNER JOIN the extra tables (and [posts] data again) on to the temp table and return that instead or do temp tables impact too much when used in that way?

Comment: @Modded, sorry I couldn't understand enough to make an assessment. Selecting what you want server side into a temp table and using it in the update should be fast enough. That select of selecting the post ids might be optimized and it may be your real question.

Answer (score 0):

OK you didn't tag the database but from the code it is SQL server (not sure of the version, I would assume not the latest and even may be an older version).
Let's start with splitting the string. It is still not clear to me how you are generating that string. You're saying you construct it using reader("PostId") in webpage. That *reader* might be the result of an ExecuteReader, meaning you are getting it from the database? If so, getting PostIds from database and then sending back might be unnecessary trip.
For the moment, the source of it is not clear, so I would assume it is needed to be constructed as a string as you did and then sent to database to be split.
Splitting the string is the first performance point. For small strings as in your example, it may not be important taking a fraction of time with the Split() function you have. However, for large strings, that code is slow and may even time out and fail if the string is large enough. I would suggest changing that to a CLR function.

You can use this code to do that (you may try this on a new test database if you will before applying to yours):

First if CLR is not enabled, it needs to be enabled:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', '1';
RECONFIGURE;
```

And execute this code to add the function (SQL 2017 and later, for older versions,  dbo.sp_add_trusted_assembly doesn't exists, instead SET TRUSTWORTHY ON is a way to do it - not sure if that would be a recommended thing to do):

```
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ufn_SplitString]')
          AND type IN ( N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT' )
)
    DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_SplitString];
GO
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.[assemblies] AS [a]
    WHERE [a].[name] = 'SQLUtils'
          AND [a].[is_user_defined] = 1
)
    DROP ASSEMBLY SqlUtils;
GO
DECLARE @ta VARBINARY(64);
SELECT @ta = hash
FROM sys.trusted_assemblies AS ta
WHERE description = N'SQL CLR Utils';
IF @ta IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    EXEC dbo.sp_drop_trusted_assembly @hash = @ta;
END;
GO

EXEC dbo.sp_add_trusted_assembly @hash = 0xCEB076E6BB8C51E08743269F6BA1AC0BB3C6E2E25B78085918DBAEE60BFC88ED45EEE861CC571DBDEDF0AD7252AEF9D1DD51DB94E6E46C69F24D0C518A8E2D98,
                                 @description = N'SQL CLR Utils';

CREATE ASSEMBLY SQLUtils AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM 0x4D5A90000300000004000000FFFF0000B800000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
800000000E1FBA0E00B409CD21B8014CCD21546869732070726F6772616D2063616E6E6F742062652072756E20696E20444F53206D6F64652E0D0D0A\
2400000000000000504500004C01030061F3D4630000000000000000E00022200B013000001600000006000000000000BA3400000020000000400000\
0000001000200000000200000400000000000000060000000000000000800000000200003AD200000300608500001000001000000000100000100000\
00000000100000000000000000000000683400004F000000004000007803000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000C00000030330000\
1C0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000080000000000000000000000\
082000004800000000000000000000002E74657874000000C0140000002000000016000000020000000000000000000000000000200000602E727372\
6300000078030000004000000004000000180000000000000000000000000000400000402E72656C6F6300000C0000000060000000020000001C0000\
00000000000000000000000040000042000000000000000000000000000000009C340000000000004800000002000500982200001810000009000000\
000000000000000000000000B03200008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003602036F1B00000A\
28020000062A5A1FFE730800000625027D0700000425037D090000042A4E0302741F000001281C00000A731D00000A512A1E02281E00000A2A2E7306\
00000680010000042A8203281F00000A2D16036F2000000A16310D03166F2100000A282200000A2A162A6602281E00000A02037D0300000402282300\
000A7D050000042A1B3002001B00000001000011027B030000040A061FFD2E040617330A00DE0702280B000006DC2A00011000000200110002130007\
000000001B300300E800000002000011027B030000040B072C0E07173BA8000000160ADDCE00000002157D03000004027B06000004282400000A3AAC\
000000027B080000048E2D36027B060000047201000070282500000A7E02000004252D17267E01000004FE0607000006732600000A25800200000428\
0100002B2B14027B06000004027B08000004176F2800000A0D090C02086F1800000A7D0A000004021FFD7D030000042B28027B0A0000046F1500000A\
13040211047D0400000402177D03000004170ADE2D021FFD7D03000004027B0A0000046F1400000A2DCB02280B00000602147D0A000004160ADE0702\
2809000006DC062A0110000004000000DFDF0007000000006E02157D03000004027B0A0000042C0B027B0A0000046F1300000A2A1E027B040000042A\
1A732900000A7A00133002004300000003000011027B030000041FFE3318027B05000004282300000A330B02167D03000004020A2B07167308000006\
0A06027B070000047D0600000406027B090000047D08000004062A1E02280F0000062A0042534A4201000100000000000C00000076342E302E333033\
31390000000005006C00000044050000237E0000B0050000D006000023537472696E677300000000800C00000800000023555300880C000010000000\
2347554944000000980C00008003000023426C6F6200000000000000020000015717A20B090A000000FA013300160000010000002600000004000000\
0A000000100000000800000005000000290000001A000000030000000100000002000000020000000700000003000000010000000400000002000000\
010000000000800301000000000006009E02B60406001F03B6040600870184040F00D60400000600AF01940306008102940306004D02940306000603\
94030600BE0294030600D70294030600E401940306009B0197040600790197040600300294030600FF013D0306006B058D030A006C02D8030A00D700\
D803060009012205060021018D030600C601B60406002A008C000600F2028D030A005205E50406005E01B60406005F008D03060015018D030600F303\
2205060038008C00060018028404060066038D030A005703E5040600CA038D030600B9058D030E00AD06030512000A01BE03060035058D030600A603\
8D03000000006A000000000001000100010010007803FA044100010001000321100088000000410001000500030110001B0000004100030008003600\
66006E01160001007201010053017A01010097067D010100C2007A01010069057D0106007D047D0101006005800106005B0580010100460084015020\
00000000960061038B0101005E20000000009100CF03920103007520000000009600F9009D0105008920000000008618700406000700912000000000\
91187604A501070089200000000086187004060007009D200000000083000A00A9010700BE20000000008618700401000800D82000000000E1013801\
06000900102100000000E101A406200009001422000000008100510006000900302200000000E1092A06AE010900382200000000E101720506000900\
302200000000E1096C062F000900402200000000E101FF03B20109008F2200000000E101430442000900000001006905000002006005000001006905\
00000200600500000100BC0302000200A500000001007B0400000100530104000A0004004D000400060004006D000400710009007004010011007004\
0600190070040A0029007004100031007004100039007004100041007004100049007004100051007004100059007004100061007004150069007004\
1000710070041000790070041000890070040600A90070041A00B90070040600C90070040600D9004B010600E100A40620000C008B062A00E1009105\
0600E1008B062F00140062043900990062044200F10070040600F900B3064700010197054C00C10070045300810070040600F900E6005A00F9006D03\
5F00F900480563000901A30568001101A7006D00F900BF065A001901B30585001C0070049300210126019900F900B305B40031017004060020007B00\
A0022E000B00C2012E001300CB012E001B00EA012E002300F3012E002B0001022E00330001022E003B0001022E004300F3012E004B0007022E005300\
01022E005B0001022E0063001F022E006B0049022E0073005602400083005503630093007A03830093007A0384008B007A030001D3007A032001D300\
7A038001D3007A03A001D3007A03C001D3007A03E001D3007A030002D3007A0371007500BE00040001000000C505BA0100000306BE0102000C000300\
02000E000500040012002700040014002900040018002B0004001A002D0004001C002F0004001E003100040020003300240033008C00048000000100\
00000000000001000000CC00FA040000040000000000000000000000C3007F0000000000040000000000000000000000C30073000000000004000000\
0000000000000000C3008D0300000000040000000000000000000000C3002C010000000003000200040002004F00B00000000000003C3E395F5F315F\
30003C53706C69747465723E625F5F315F30003C53706C69747465723E645F5F310049456E756D657261626C6560310049456E756D657261746F7260\
31003C3E375F5F7772617031003C3E6D5F5F46696E616C6C79310046756E636032003C3E39003C4D6F64756C653E0053797374656D2E44617461006D\
73636F726C6962003C3E630053797374656D2E436F6C6C656374696F6E732E47656E65726963006765745F43757272656E744D616E61676564546872\
6561644964003C3E6C5F5F696E697469616C546872656164496400446174614163636573734B696E640049734E756C6C4F7257686974655370616365\
0046696C6C537472696E675461626C650049456E756D657261626C650049446973706F7361626C6500547970650057686572650053797374656D2E43\
6F72650053797374656D2E49446973706F7361626C652E446973706F7365003C3E315F5F737461746500436F6D70696C657247656E65726174656441\
747472696275746500477569644174747269627574650044656275676761626C6541747472696275746500436F6D56697369626C6541747472696275\
746500417373656D626C795469746C65417474726962757465004974657261746F7253746174654D616368696E654174747269627574650041737365\
6D626C7954726164656D61726B417474726962757465005461726765744672616D65776F726B41747472696275746500446562756767657248696464\
656E41747472696275746500417373656D626C7946696C6556657273696F6E41747472696275746500417373656D626C79436F6E6669677572617469\
6F6E4174747269627574650053716C46756E6374696F6E41747472696275746500417373656D626C794465736372697074696F6E4174747269627574\
6500436F6D70696C6174696F6E52656C61786174696F6E7341747472696275746500417373656D626C7950726F647563744174747269627574650041\
7373656D626C79436F7079726967687441747472696275746500506172616D417272617941747472696275746500417373656D626C79436F6D70616E\
794174747269627574650052756E74696D65436F6D7061746962696C6974794174747269627574650053797374656D2E52756E74696D652E56657273\
696F6E696E670053716C537472696E670053706C6974537472696E67006765745F4C656E6774680053716C5574696C0053514C5574696C732E646C6C\
0053797374656D0053797374656D2E5265666C656374696F6E004E6F74537570706F72746564457863657074696F6E006F0053797374656D2E4C696E\
7100436861720053706C6974746572004D6963726F736F66742E53716C5365727665722E5365727665720049456E756D657261746F72005379737465\
6D2E436F6C6C656374696F6E732E47656E657269632E49456E756D657261626C653C53797374656D2E537472696E673E2E476574456E756D65726174\
6F720053797374656D2E436F6C6C656374696F6E732E49456E756D657261626C652E476574456E756D657261746F72002E63746F72002E6363746F72\
003C3E335F5F730053797374656D2E446961676E6F73746963730053797374656D2E52756E74696D652E496E7465726F705365727669636573005379\
7374656D2E52756E74696D652E436F6D70696C6572536572766963657300446562756767696E674D6F6465730053797374656D2E446174612E53716C\
54797065730053514C5574696C730053797374656D2E546578742E526567756C617245787072657373696F6E730053797374656D2E436F6C6C656374\
696F6E7300537472696E6753706C69744F7074696F6E73006765745F43686172730053716C4368617273003C3E335F5F736570617261746F7273004F\
626A6563740053797374656D2E436F6C6C656374696F6E732E49456E756D657261746F722E5265736574006F705F496D706C696369740049734C6574\
7465724F7244696769740053706C697400456E7669726F6E6D656E740053797374656D2E436F6C6C656374696F6E732E47656E657269632E49456E75\
6D657261746F723C53797374656D2E537472696E673E2E43757272656E740053797374656D2E436F6C6C656374696F6E732E49456E756D657261746F\
722E43757272656E740053797374656D2E436F6C6C656374696F6E732E47656E657269632E49456E756D657261746F723C53797374656D2E53747269\
6E673E2E6765745F43757272656E740053797374656D2E436F6C6C656374696F6E732E49456E756D657261746F722E6765745F43757272656E74003C\
3E325F5F63757272656E74004D6F76654E65787400526567657800546F4368617241727261790049734E756C6C4F72456D7074790000000000055C00\
62000000233D59D645D99849B7DE049542552E5000042001010803200001052001011111042001010E04200101020520010112510320000205151275\
010E04200013000320001C05151259010E08200015127501130004200012710420001D030600011180810E06200101118081040001020E0320000804\
20010308040001020303000008030701080F07050208151259010E151259010E0E0600021D0E0E0E06151269020E02052002011C1816100102151259\
011E00151259011E00151269021E0002030A010E0920021D0E1D03118095040701121008B77A5C561934E08980A00024000004800000940000000602\
000000240000525341310004000001000100858173EEBF9F0EA6C8BFB7F1F3E5D6238024C53672D0B039376C1BB97CED6DE9A5691A1E0A66156709DC\
7DBDB2B05D5100920CA9760A6C2564ED6B0FD3902607D1D5D77423550EAE3E32F8B33F6DCDB48237AB6A03168459A775F7BFEDD50E8FF32E97B29C47\
AB96874597204608BA5C13F538F0900EAD2412D1CE105904CDB50306120C0706151269020E0202060802060E03061D030606151275010E060002124D\
0E0E0A0002151259010E0E1D03070002011C10126103000001042001020E0320000E072000151275010E0328000E0328001C0801000800000000001E\
01000100540216577261704E6F6E457863657074696F6E5468726F7773010801000200000000000D01000853514C5574696C73000005010000000017\
010012436F7079726967687420C2A920203230323200002901002436643732343736392D346666632D343966652D386561612D666136313330386138\
62313800000C010007312E302E302E3000004901001A2E4E45544672616D65776F726B2C56657273696F6E3D76342E380100540E144672616D65776F\
726B446973706C61794E616D65122E4E4554204672616D65776F726B20342E3880B3010002005455794D6963726F736F66742E53716C536572766572\
2E5365727665722E446174614163636573734B696E642C2053797374656D2E446174612C2056657273696F6E3D342E302E302E302C2043756C747572\
653D6E65757472616C2C205075626C69634B6579546F6B656E3D623737613563353631393334653038390A4461746141636365737300000000540E11\
46696C6C526F774D6574686F644E616D650F46696C6C537472696E675461626C652401001F53514C5574696C732E53716C5574696C2B3C53706C6974\
7465723E645F5F310000040100000000B6ECAB35C4CC0AC896D3D3404EB66253CEF0E979635EF6ABBD1F00C96573B53D179A64C90C920112116D5900\
6D514E9A2B8F93C3866239B484803DC130276DAED8404492A11ACEB072A4DDF8C297A913673ED2417AE3FECFBFB5B2A7D0343A05EF2D3DEDFEC82553\
9BBA85A0C2AD2956F73B8DE88E4F5C558BB7065C9BCA81A50000000061F3D46300000000020000001C0100004C3300004C15000052534453849790AE\
7336D34085CC0E2F186C71EC01000000443A5C53514C53706C6974434C525C53514C5574696C735C6F626A5C52656C656173655C53514C5574696C73\
2E7064620000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000903400000000000000000000AA3400000020000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000009C340000000000000000000000005F436F72446C6C4D61696E006D73636F7265652E646C6C0000000000FF25\
002000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001001000000018000080000000000000000000000000\
000001000100000030000080000000000000000000000000000001000000000048000000584000001C03000000000000000000001C03340000005600\
53005F00560045005200530049004F004E005F0049004E0046004F0000000000BD04EFFE00000100000001000000000000000100000000003F000000\
000000000400000002000000000000000000000000000000440000000100560061007200460069006C00650049006E0066006F000000000024000400\
00005400720061006E0073006C006100740069006F006E00000000000000B0047C020000010053007400720069006E006700460069006C0065004900\
6E0066006F0000005802000001003000300030003000300034006200300000001A000100010043006F006D006D0065006E0074007300000000000000\
22000100010043006F006D00700061006E0079004E0061006D00650000000000000000003A0009000100460069006C00650044006500730063007200\
69007000740069006F006E0000000000530051004C005500740069006C00730000000000300008000100460069006C00650056006500720073006900\
6F006E000000000031002E0030002E0030002E00300000003A000D00010049006E007400650072006E0061006C004E0061006D006500000053005100\
4C005500740069006C0073002E0064006C006C00000000004800120001004C006500670061006C0043006F0070007900720069006700680074000000\
43006F0070007900720069006700680074002000A90020002000320030003200320000002A00010001004C006500670061006C005400720061006400\
65006D00610072006B007300000000000000000042000D0001004F0072006900670069006E0061006C00460069006C0065006E0061006D0065000000\
530051004C005500740069006C0073002E0064006C006C0000000000320009000100500072006F0064007500630074004E0061006D00650000000000\
530051004C005500740069006C00730000000000340008000100500072006F006400750063007400560065007200730069006F006E00000031002E00\
30002E0030002E003000000038000800010041007300730065006D0062006C0079002000560065007200730069006F006E00000031002E0030002E00\
30002E003000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003000000C000000BC3400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION ufn_SplitString
(
    @s NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @separators NVARCHAR(1000) = ''
)
RETURNS TABLE
(
    s NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
EXTERNAL NAME SQLUtils.[SQLUtils.SqlUtil].SplitString;
GO
```

Finally you can test the added function:

```
SELECT s FROM dbo.ufn_SplitString('a|b|x','|');
SELECT s FROM dbo.ufn_SplitString('a,b,x',',');
SELECT s FROM dbo.ufn_SplitString('a,b|x','|,');
```

(I will continue on a new reply just to keep this thing not to long + splitting is itself a different part of the question)

Comment: Hi yes it is SQL and am unsure which version, although about to be updated to latest at some point. The initial data would be from something as simple as SELECT TOP 20 * FROM [Posts] ORDER BY [POSTID] DESC but with [Users] table and [Groups] tables added in for extra information

Comment: @Modded, all of them could be a single SQL statement and doesn't need to get data from SQL server, generate the string and execute another command. I will add another sample in the other reply.

Comment: I think (pseudo code here please forgive) that what I'm looking for is SELECT TOP 20 * AND SET [Viewcount]=[Viewcount]+1 FROM [Posts] ORDER BY [POSTID] DESC or something very similar in functionality so to avoid the code behind working out ID's into a string and firing it back if that makes any sense, or a way to collect ID's into the @temp and update as above before whilst collecting the [posts] results in one stored procedure. My ideal is to cut out running 2 procedures!

Comment: I think instead of saying viewcount just call it "how many times this row has been selected count"

Comment: @Modded, I added another SQL in the other one. There one thing I am not sure if that needs a COUNT() or PostIds would be  unique with added joins and other table data.